# MinGW installation failure

Tags: c++, windows-7, installation, mingw

Hey all I am having trouble with the MinGW installation process. I have downloaded the MinGW installer and selected the packages I wanted ( mainly the c++ compiler ) and when it is all said and done I have no g++.exe in my MinGW bin directory. during the installation phase it says

> ERROR: MinGW/bin/c++.exe: extraction failure.
>   ERROR: unexpected end of archive reading content record
>   ERRORL: unexpected end of archive reading header record

Can't seems to find any information on this specific problem, If anyone has any idea what causes this I owuld really appreciate your input. I am doing this on windows 7.

Comment: Is the problem still exists? If not please accept an answer or right your solution as an answer and accept that. If the problem still exists please post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't faced such problem. But have u checked this [link.](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite) Please check the link and let us know your update on this.